# How can I embed React element into component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React Js and I have a beginner question:
I create a React element

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
```

I do not understand, why do I need braces to put element inside component

```
const Module = () => 
<div>
{element}  // why {element} not element
</div>;
ReactDOM.render( <Module/>, document.getElementById('root') );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why {element} not element

Because without the `{...}`, you're just writing HTML text; the div would have the word "element" in it. The `{...}` indicate an *expression* that should be evaluated and used where the `{...}` is; in this case, that expression is just a variable reference, and so it embeds the value of the variable as of when that expression is evaluated (when your `Module` stateless functional component is called).

Comment: Is it a pure javascript thing? I mean - expression. Or React thing

Comment: @kilogram: It's a [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html) thing.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier for you go go through the [*Hello World!*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) example on the react website than explain it peace meal in stackoverflow. What you are referring to is JSX which is an html look alike syntax created by the react team. The braces are a way to inject the variable into JSX and makes the code much more readable. Could you imagine how confusing it would be if you had a variable inserted without braces. You'd look at element and say, did they mean the word element or the variable element?